# How reset/refresh the trigger in jquery

Tags: jquery, triggers, refresh, reset

How reset the trigger

```
$("#poButton").click(function(){

    $('.myPrint').trigger('click');

 });
```

When I first time click on the button(i.e. poButton), trigger trig one time, on second click 2 times and on third click 3 times and so on...

How to reset/refresh the trigger? because when I fresh the browser , it refresh.

Comment: how many elements are selected each time by $(".myPrint")?

Comment: You need to add the code for the click listener for `$('.myPrint')`. It doesn't make any sense otherwise

Answer (score 0):

If you want to unbind an event listener from an object call `.unbind()` on the object, like this:

```
$('#foo').unbind();
```

You can even specify what event you want to unbind:

```
$('#foo').unbind('click');
```

If you want to 'refresh' the event listener just unbind them all and bind **1** new event listener to it.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing from your comment There's two options. If you only expect one element with the class `myPrint`then you should fix that issue Ie. figuring out why you have multiple if you on the other side just wish to have the method called once regards less of how many elements with the class myPrint you have simply call the function attached as an event handler or do as below

```
$(".myPrint").first().click();
```

personally I'd prefer to call the function directly instead of triggering the event.